# is Media query different between ios and android?

Tags: flutter

i try to fill background of picture use mediaquery to fill picture. ios work fine but android its doesn't work i use media query to fill picture and then got this
[image]

can i make another way to fill it ?
here is code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildBackgroud(context),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()),
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: size * 0.3,
                    ),
                    buildTopic('General Information'),
                    buildTextBoxEmail(size),
                    buildTextBoxUserName(size),
                    buildTextBoxPassword(size),
                    buildButton(size, context),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate))
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

background method is

```
SvgPicture buildBackgroud(BuildContext context) {
    return SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/images/bg.svg',
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  }
```

Comment: use this package to solve the issue 
flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.2

Comment: thanks. i have done it with wrap with container then set width and height in container maybe i will try flutter_screenutil

Comment: flutter_screenutil is very good library In terms of responsiveness

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, wrapping `SvgPicture.asset()` into `SizedBox` and giving full screen `height` and `width` into it in your `buildBackground` function.

```
SvgPicture buildBackgroud(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/images/bg.svg',
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
    );
  }
```